# Under which metrizable topologies is $\{e_1, e_2, \cdots\}$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

My professor proved today that $\{e_1, e_2, \cdots \}$ is a Schauder basis for $\ell^p$ (where, of course $e_i = (0, \cdots, 1, 0, \cdots$ with $1$ at the i-th entry). I asked if it was a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ as well, and she pointed out that we need a norm (and hence a metrizable topology) to talk about basis in infinite dimensional spaces (actually I'm not sure I agree that we need anything other than a topology, but that's another subject), so I wondered if $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the product topology has $\{e_1, e_2, \cdots\}$ (which turns out to be just $\ell^{\infty}$ **EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, this is wrong**) as a basis... and I don't know the answer to that either. So, are there metrizable topology where that set is a basis?

Of course, intuition would tell me that yes, it's a basis, but we all know how tricky intuition is when dealing with infinite dimensional stuff.

Comment: $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ is not "just $\ell^\infty$".  Note that the open, unit $\ell^\infty$ ball fails to be open in the product topology

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The product topology is metrizable by the uniform metric, right? And the uniform metric is the same as the $\ell^{\infty}$ metric, correct? So what's wrong with my reasoning here?

Comment: The uniform metric is very different from the product topology!  The product topology is the topology of pointwise convergence, not uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks! I must have remembered wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure the standard "basis vectors" are a Schauder basis for $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology.  This follows essentially immediately from the fact that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ converges iff it converges on each coordinate.

As for the general question, there is a rather uninteresting answer.  Let $X$ be *any* metrizable topological vector space with a Schauder basis $(x_n)$ and which has algebraic dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$ (the last condition is automatic if $X$ is a Banach space, say).  Then we can pick a vector space isomorphism between $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which maps $x_n$ to $e_n$, and transport the topology of $X$ along this linear isomorphism to get a metrizable topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ compatible with the vector space structure such that $(e_n)$ is a Schauder basis.

(The point here is that if you are thinking of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ as merely a vector space with special elements $(e_n)$, that is a *very* weak structure: you just have a vector space of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ together with a sequence of linearly independent elements, and so you can identify it with any other such vector space with a sequence of linearly independent elements.)